# .HTAccess multiple redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to achieve that if a user write:

```
http://www.example.com/url/index.html
http://www.example.com/url/
https://example.com/url/index.html
https://example.com/url/
```

will be **always** redirect to:

```
https://www.example.com/url/
```

So I write this redirect istruction in .htaccess (I'm not an expert of this so I think it could be here the problem) and it seems to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that from some SEO tools it seems that it make the work in more than 1 redirection. Infact I think that if the user look for:

http://example.com/url/

it redirects to

https://example.com/url/

after to

https://www.example.com/url/

How can I change the previuos code to make it better and make everything with 1 redirection?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten your http to https redirect rules. Instead of using two separate rules for `http` and `htttps://www` you can just use a single rewrite rule that will handle both in one redirection .

```
RewriteEngine on
# http to https and non-www to www
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
# remove index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.index\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this htaccess.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, anyway I try the code you suggested but with the server answer me with 500 error code...could you check it please?

Comment: @pinguinone I tested the code on my server. It's working fine . Please check your log file for info about the 500 error.

Comment: Ok, I try to understand where is the problem and it in row: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(. +)$  if I put your code except this row it goes well. The server tell me this error: [Tue Jun 12 17:58:52.010204 2018] [core:alert] [pid 17834] [client 95.224.198.32:37062] /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters"

Comment: @pinguinone  There was a space in the  capture group `(. +)$` .I have removed it and should work now.

Comment: Fantastic! It works like a charm! Thanks so much for your help!